# VBA function error

Tags: function, vba

I am new to VBA and have an issue with calling my function:

My function is as follows:

```
Function pricing(priceSchedule As String, cellValue As String)

MsgBox (priceSchedule)
MsgBox (cellValue)

End Function
```

When I call it:

```
pricing("Master Sheet", "G8")
```

I get the error:

```
Compile error: 
Expected: =
```

Could someone please help? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Normally a `Function` returns something and what you have here should be a `Sub`.

You should just remove the curly brackets for the MsgBox calls.

```
MsgBox priceSchedule
MsgBox cellValue
```

If you use the function without storing a value then

`Call pricing("Master Sheet", "G8")`

Or

`pricing "Master Sheet", "G8"`